Different between two date, result in years and days not month in php
I would like differences between two date results in Years and days not month
I have tried as below

$date1 = new DateTime("2023-01-01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2024-04-10");

$difference = date_diff($date1, $date2);

$years = $difference->y;
$months = $difference->m;
$days = $difference->d;

echo "$years Years";
echo "<br />";
echo "$months month";
echo "<br />";
echo "$days days";


and got result as
1 Years
3 month
9 days
I need the result as
1 Years
101 days
Could any one help on this.
I tried many ways but no one worked

This question is similar to: Finding the number of days between two dates. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  (I assume this question is about PHP)

Problem is that "a year" is not a fixed count of days. So, first obtain the difference in full years from the start date, then add that to the start date and, finally, find the remaining count of days until the end date.

Hi @luuk, Thanks for your comments. Actually what I am looking is not similar as your link. I need result on total Year and days.

@OhidulIslam Please [edit] your question to show/explain the math why the difference of these two dates are 1 year and 101 days. Depending on how you do the calculations, the differences could be 1 year and 99 days, 100 days or 101 days. Also add other sample dates and the calculated difference you want. These other dates should handle special cases like leap years and other problematic date ranges.

Finaly I did it. I got my expeted result by below code
$date1 = new DateTime("2023-01-01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2024-04-10");

$difference = date_diff($date1, $date2);

$years = $difference->y;

// Calculate total days without including the years
$date1_copy = clone $date1;
$date1_copy->modify("+$years years");
$daysDifference = ($date1_copy->diff($date2)->days)+1;

echo "$years Years";
echo "<br />";
echo "$daysDifference Days";


Because of Stack Overflow's goal of consolidating content, if you have any unique insights to share on this topic, please move your content to the dupe target.
